# Media queries for ipad pro and laptops

Tags: ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, ipad

What is the correct way to handle media queries for iPad Pro and several laptops?

So normally you would do this `(min-device-width: 1024px) and (max-device-width: 1366px)` for an iPad pro. However when using Chrome's dev tools you'll see that there are laptop screen sizes like 1280x800px and 1440x900px.

The problem I'm facing now is that those screen sizes overlap. 
Is there a "standard" way of solving such problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "standard" way of handling this would be to not use device specific media queries.

https://responsivedesign.is/articles/why-you-dont-need-device-specific-breakpoints/

**EDIT:** Added a Snippet below showing how you can use only `max-width` without using `min-width`, thus avoiding any overlap.

```css
div {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: grey;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 780px){
 div {
   background-color: green;
 }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
 div {
   background-color: blue;
 }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 300px){
 div {
   background-color: yellow;
 }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Ok thx. Learned something, interesting stuff. However how do you do that what's described. There's no real solution in there....

Comment: By only using `max-width`. (or min-width if you are doing mobile first layouts.)

Comment: I've added a snippet example.